# How can I do a dictionary format with f-string in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, f-string

my code is as below

```
aaa = "['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']"
REQUEST = f'{"siteUrls": {aaa}}'
print(REQUEST)
```

I've tried

```
aaa = "['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']"
REQUEST = {"siteUrls": {}}.format(aaa)
print(REQUEST)
```

and

```
aaa = "['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']"
REQUEST = {"siteUrls": %s}%aaa
print(REQUEST)
```

all of them didn't work
REQUEST must be dict.
please help.

Comment: Why is `aaa` a string and not a list, and why are you using string formation instead of the `json` module to build the request payload?

Comment: What you *probably* want is `aaa = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']` (you may need to figure out how to parse a given string back to a Python list first), then `REQUEST = {'siteUrls': aaa}`.

Comment: because I'm beginner. if aaa is a list is it better to resolve this issue? @chepner

Comment: Yes; build the data structure first, *then* encode as JSON (if necessary) as the very last step before sending the request.

Comment: aaa is a var, collects urls of products. so I think aaa should be a list. @chepner

Comment: could you provide codes please @chepner

Comment: What produces `aaa` in the first place? It should just not create the string from whatever list it starts with.

Comment: `aaa = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com'] REQUEST = { "siteUrls": [f'{aaa[0]}']}`
this works, thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
aaa = "['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']"
REQUEST = {"siteUrls": f"{aaa}"}
print(REQUEST)
```

Comment: `aaa = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']`
`REQUEST = { "siteUrls": [f'{aaa[0]}']}`

it works! thank yhou @r3a9670